# MvcSerializer().Deserialize(serialized,SerializationMode....)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, serialization

In asp.net mvc 3.0, I want to Deserialize and object which is stored in an input hidden filed.

Here is the Serializable class :

> [Serializable]
>
> ```
> public class RegistrationData
> {
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string Email { get; set; }
> }
> ```

and the this is how i generate hidden field :

> <%: Html.Serialize("regData", Model, 
>   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.SerializationMode.Signed)%>

but when I Deserialize it through following method, I get null values for my object :

> var serialized = Request.Form["regData"];
>
> ```
>         if (serialized != null)
>         {
>             regData = (RegistrationData)newMvcSerializer().Deserialize(serialized,SerializationMode.Signed); 
>
>         }
> ```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: You mean the regData instance is null?  The instance is "empty" (e.g. non-null, but where the Name and Email properties are null)?  Request.Form["regData"] is null?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model**

```
 public class RegistrationData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
       @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Name) 
       @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Email)
 }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Foo(RegistrationData form)
{
      //do
      //form.Name   ->> get name
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476736/mvc-3-and-html-serialize-asp-net-4-mvc3